# Norm of y vector in Eigenvalue Decomposition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am following along with Stephen Boyd's Convex Optimization course and am a little confused about the way to find eigenvalues. The method used here is to find $$\underset{\mid \mid y\mid \mid _2 = 1}{y^T Xy} $$ but I'm a little confused about why $||y||_2$ should be  $1$ My knowledge of how to find eigenvalues is solving for $\lambda, v$ in $Av = \lambda v$ and the form presented above seems to be the result of a decomposition. However, I am unsure why the norm of the vector $y$ is 1 and what significance it has.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Lecture slide containing how to find maximum eigenvalue of a matrix. Boyd 2014]

Comment: have you see the proof why the supremum is the maximum eigenvalue? in that proof what happens if $\| y \|_2$ takes a different value? Or is your question why do we need to constraint $y$ at all?

Comment: You get your equation $Av=\lambda v$ when you apply the Lagrange method of multipliers to $v^TAv$ subject to $\|v\|=1$. It has to be the Euclidean norm for this to be the case.

Comment: This is an equality, not really a method for finding eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is symmetric then it can be orthogonally diagonalised, say $U^T X U = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \}$.

Since $U$ is orthogonal, $\|U^Ty\| = \|y\|$, so
$\max_{\|y\| = 1} y^T X y = \max_{\|y\| = 1} y^T U^TX Uy = \max_{\|y\|=1} \sum_k \lambda_k y_k^2$.

It is straightforward to see that
$\max_{\|y\|=1} \sum_k \lambda_k y_k^2 \le \lambda_\max$, and by choosing
$y$ to be the unit vector corresponding to $\lambda_\max$ we get equality.